# Method showing alert in App Delegate fails because it's rootViewController is not in the View Hierarcy

Tags: ios, appdelegate, uialertcontroller

During development of my iOS application, I would like to be able to show the user a dialog if a serious bug occurs.

on SO, found that this could be achieved with adding something like the following to my AppDelegate class

```
- (void) notifyUserAboutSeriousBugWithMessage:(NSString *)message {
    UIAlertController* alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Serious bug: Alert developer"
                                                                   message:message
                                                            preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    UIAlertAction* defaultAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Continue" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                          handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {}];
    [alert addAction:defaultAction];

    [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:^{}];
}
```

However, when I run this, i get an error message saying I'm `Attempting to present <A> on <B> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!`

My application is using a storyboard and the `Entry/Start point <B>` is a Splash Screen (-viewController). [This is not contained in a NavigationController]

When I'm done with the splash screen, I use a Modal Segue to show "the rest" of the app.

So how can I workaround this? In my app delegate, I want to get some view controller that will be in the view hierarcy and show my Alert in it's view.

(The reason I want to put this in the app delegate is that I want to present error alerts from classes that are not view controllers)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's probably because you already have a presented `viewController` on top of your `rootViewController`. You need to present your alert on top of the topmost view controller.

Here is how you can get the topmost controller :

```
UIViewController *topViewController = self.window.rootViewController;
while (topViewController.presentedViewController) {
    topViewController = topViewController.presentedViewController;
}
```

You can then do :

```
[topViewController presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: That did it. Thank you.